# Windows 10 Anniversary Update fails with error 0xc000000f

Tags: bsod, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

I enrolled my machine in the Release Preview ring of the Insider program. The update downloads, prepares to install and then requests a restart. It 'prepares to configure Windows' (I believe), and after the reboot it blue-screens:

> ### Recovery
>
> **Your PC/Device needs to be repaired**
>
> A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.
>
> Error code: 0xc000000f
>
> You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.
>
> **Press Enter to try again**
> **Press F8 for Startup Settings**
> **Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings**
> **Press F9 to use a different operating system**

Pressing Enter or F8 just seems to refresh the screen. Pressing Escape leads me to the UEFI configuration screen and F9 returns me to Windows, without having updated. It notifies me afterwards that 'Updates have failed to install'.

The machine has BitLocker enabled, but I'm unsure if that is causing the issue. Also hesitant to disable it, because company policy enforces it.

WindowsUpdate.log doesn't show any meaningful message. A ton of content that seems to indicate success and then:

```
2016-08-01 09:53:10.8798806 628   1248  Shared          * END * Service exit Exit code = 0x240001
2016-08-01 10:00:43.0283959 628   9832  Agent           WU client version 10.0.10586.494
```

Which, as far as I can tell, shows one message before the reboot, and one immediately after. Of course there are a lot of messages after the reboot as well. What can I do to either resolve or diagnose this further?

Comment: You should disable Bitlocker before you update

Comment: @Ramhound Is there any documentation that references this? Why doesn't the update process complain about this beforehand?

Comment: Perhaps wait for the final version of the update?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal According to several sources ([Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/07/windows-10-anniversary-update-is-ready-to-go-and-free-for-just-a-few-more-days/) amongst others), build 14393 **is** the final version.

Comment: WindowsUpdate.log has truly only those two lines? It is usually very verbose.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal It has a lot more, but those seem to only relate to the preparation before the reboot and after the subsequent reboot where it detects the failure.

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk- It is the final build, but the vesion of that build, isn't going to be 14393.5 whch is what you are downloading.  You should still disable bitlocker then try the update though.

Comment: "because company policy enforces it." - You should wait till the company pushes this update or get the permission required to disable until you can update and enable it again.  If you don't have the permission to do that, then we really can't help you, how you get around company policies isn't something we can help you with.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that, but it's ridiculous that Windows can't simply show a message like "you've BitLocker'ed your system drive, so we can't install this update right now". Also, it's ridiculous that the update won't just install on a BitLocker'ed drive; it's not that uncommon these days.

Comment: You had to disable Bitlocker to upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the RTM update installed without a hitch. The problem was probably related to switching to an Insider Preview build. I haven't verified that, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing on my HP laptop. Windows couldn't repair itself because of bitlocker.

I did regain access to Windows by starting with my network disconnected. Then I could access a command line an unlock bitlocker using

```
manage-bde -unlock {-recoverypassword <Password>|-recoverykey <PathToExternalKeyFile>} <Drive>
```

and then turning it of with

```
manage-bde -off <Drive>
```

After rebooting all repair options are available and Windows will be able to reboot.
On my pc, logging in with my finger print also stopped functioning correctly so I suspect the problem lies with the TPM, the Trusted Platform Module.

I only succeeded in re-enabling bitlocker after I disabled the TPM module in my BIOS. However, this means it is currently using software encryption, instead of the hardware accellerated version. And I'm still not able to re-enable finger print logon.

Comment: I had the same problem on my Dell Latitude e7240. I ultimately had to disable bitlocker entirely, and cannot get it to re-enable, even after decrypting, the drive, clearing the TPM. When running the Bitlocker test (which should be on by default) I get `eventid 24604: The boot configuration options did not match expected values during restart.` followed by `eventid 24609: A key was not available from required sources during restart.` and Bitlocker will of course not encrypt the drive. Tried updating chipset drivers, TPM drivers, BIOS, etc. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this thread at Microsoft TechNet Forum: [After update 1607 no TPM function](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7b754050-f8e5-4bc0-821a-fa8c5a0feaac/after-update-1607-no-tpm-function?forum=win10itprosecurity)

It describe similar problems and possible workaround for this. I see some situation where new BIOS solve it for HP NTB, but for Dell not. So wait for fix from Microsoft side currently.